# Look at qty of 1 col if criteria 1 and 2 are met

Tags: excel

I have spreed sheet and need to Count the how man WED in one column and If DVD in another and look at then qty in in a 3rd column and do this for the entire spreed sheet and give me a to number of WED DVDS.  I will will repeat this for THU DVDs WED DIGITAL and THU DIGITAL  How do I do this?

Comment: Please add some code and rephrase your question so we can understand and help you.

Comment: =COUNTIFS(L2:L43,"WED",M2:M43,"DVD")

This is what I have now and works great execpt when the qty is more than 1 the really count is off.  Wed there is the WED/THU the Qty should be 2 not 1  I need a way of have both criteras and look at the qty and and give me a accurate number.  I need to look at the row/col that it is in and give me a real number.  I need to repeat this for the array.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a matrix array for your Wed DVD example.  You should be able to extend this to get what you want.  I have assumed the Qty would be in column N.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(L2:L25="WED"),--(M2:M25="DVD"))*(N2:N25)
```

Comment: I tired that but does not seem to work.  This what I was using  =COUNTIFS(L2:L43,"WED",M2:M43,"DVD")   This was ok is only 1 qty but if 2 or 3 orders for the person,  The count is wrong and the formula is not working....  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong then.

Comment: Other than my example only going to row 25 instead of 43, I'm not sure what the problem is.  Can you post some test data so we are working from the same page?

Comment: Bracket in the wrong place.  Should only be one in front of the * and move the closed bracket to the end.